# TimeoutException android.media.SoundPool.finalize()

Tags: android, soundpool

On Android 9, this crash appears sometimes, I can't understand why:

Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException  android.media.SoundPool.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds  android.media.SoundPool.native_release (SoundPool.java) android.media.SoundPool.release (SoundPool.java:177) java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)

All works perfectly before, and now on Android 9 (SONY currently), the crash appears.

Have you got some explanations guys?

Comment: i got the same issue, any updates?

Comment: Same issue on android 8.1 LAVIE Tab E